# Java Droptarget error

Tags: java, user-interface, drag-and-drop

I have a two panel in which objects in panel1 can be dragged and dropped into panel2.
It is working well, until i load object from saved xml file and the function directly loads the object into panel2. When the time i will continue to drag another object from the panel1 to panel2 the error occurs.

i have tested adding a line  just to try. I instantiate the droptarget again and works but objects that is first loaded aren't related anymore. its like the droptarget is deleted when i load the objects.
dropTarget = new DropTarget(panel,this);

What do you think is the reason why the droptarget is deleted?

Comment: What is the error/exception output? Can you provide a simple example demonstrating the problem?

Comment: the error output is that it is null. so when i dont use the load function the drag and drop is working well. and when i load objects and when the objects are already loaded the moment i drag an object from another panel the error occurs. What i do is i instantiate the mentioned line above and the error never occurs but loaded objects and new dragged objects cannot be related anymore. Im only curious why when the load function is used the error occurs.

Comment: Do you have an example that can demonstrate the problem?